# Color area under graph in manim

Tags: python, manim

I am following this tutorial for manim: https://talkingphysics.wordpress.com/2019/01/08/getting-started-animating-with-manim-and-python-3-7/. Under heading 7.0: Graphing functions, the example shows code for plotting sine and cosine functions.

I was wondering if I could also fill the area covered between, let's say, sine function and the x-axis from x_min to x_max. I realized that the used PlotFunctions class has following hierarchy: PlotFunctions -> GraphScene -> Scene -> Container -> object (where -> denotes child of). But in this entire chain of hierarchy, I do not see a config option such as fill_color that is present in VMobject.

I'm also not readily able to locate any code that helps in doing so, although I'm sure that some really easy 1 line code must exist since this is used in so many 3blue1brown videos. I would really appreciate some help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this [github issue](https://github.com.cnpmjs.org/3b1b/manim/pull/833), it might be something your'e looking for.

It hasn't been merged onto the `main branch` so this could be a work-around for now.

Answer (score 0):

After looking more into the code, I still don't see a 1-liner code per se but did find that to color the area under the graph, a set of riemann rectangles of very small width (~0.01) are used. This makes the graph look colored.

Answer (score 0):

I used get_point_from_function() option to get the points and passed them to create a Polygon filled with colour.

you can check it [here](https://github.com/panditsomnath10016git/FSF-mathematics-python-code-archive/blob/master/FSF-2020/calculus-of-several-variables/integrals-of-multivariable-functions/fubini's-theorem/file2_surface2.py) , look at `def get_region()`